# JSF PRIMEFACES 4.0 dynamic UI Component injection

Tags: jsf-2

I need to create ui components dynamically in jsf page using managed bean.
I have ui types(inputText,textArea,Calender etc...) stored in the database.
So using these data i want to create ui components such as textfields on jsf page.

Is it possible,if yes then how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you paste the codes and point where you are stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider [Metawidget](http://metawidget.org) for this task, as it does much of the hard work around dynamically creating components (including PrimeFaces components) for you.

If you'd rather roll your own implementation, here is the correct way to create dynamic components in JSF: http://blog.kennardconsulting.com/2010/10/safely-manipulating-component-tree-with.html